# symfony form validation does not work

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, constraints, formbuilder

I have a form like this in my symfony project, note that the concerned field is not a mapped one:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

// validators and constraints
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

class ArtistWithConstraintType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $artist = $options['data'];
        $builder
            ->add('professional', 'choice', array(
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'choices' => array(false => 'You are a self-educated', true => 'You are a professional'),
                    'required' => true,
                ))
            ;

        if ($artist && $artist->getProfessional()) {
            $builder->add('artistNumber', 'text', array(
                'constraints' => array(
                                    new Length(array(
                                        'max' => 14,
                                        'min' => 14))),
                'required' => true,
                ))
            ;
        } else {
            $artist->setArtistNumber(null);
            $builder->remove('artistNumber')
            ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\Artist',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token_artist',
            // a unique key to help generate the secret token
            'intention'       => 'artist_item',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_artist';
    }
}
```

In fact, in this form I ask the artist if it's a professionnal or not. If not, no action required. If true, by an ajax method I display the field named `artistNumber`.

For now, all works well. Except the validation constraint:

```
'constraints' => array(
    new Length(array(
        'max' => 14,
        'min' => 14))),
```

Indeed, the artistNumber field have to be a string with 14 characters only, no more no less. But when I validate my form, this validation constraint is not taken into account.

I have no problem to display the form in the view, no problem with ajax or no problem to recover the user entry in the `artistNumber` field. But if the user enters a string with less or more than 14 characters length, the validation does not work either and I recover after the user entry even if it's less or more than 14 characters.

Where am I wrong here ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Validation constraint should work fine. Are you using any validation groups?

Comment: @MikhailProsalov thank you for your comment, no I don't use validation group here.

Comment: Please try to add 'mapped' => false to your artistNumber field options array.

Answer (score -1):

You have a condition before add the constraint. Check if the condition

```
$artist && $artist->getProfessional()
```

is true as you are suposing

Comment: indeed, it's a good suggestion, but i check if the `$artist && $artist->getProfessional()` is true as I supposed, and yes it is, so I don't think the problem is in the condition.